# wordpress on echo removing // from image url

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am trying to fetch image url form custum field when i am writing it inside echo string by concatinate it removing // and putting space instead of that place on echo what if i write it without string concatinate it working fine what causing me this issue how can i use both ways without making it remove // from url. Sorry for english

```
<section class="slider-wrapper" <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
echo 'style="background: url("'.get_the_post_thumbnail_url().'")"';
} else {
} ?>>
```

Comment: It looks like you haven't got the `echo` statement onwards wrapped in PHP tags. It would also make it easier to figure out what the issue is if you were to move the conditional statements out into a variable so that you don't have them sat within the markup.

Comment: it just type mistake on posting here let me update

Answer (score 0):

If there is nothing going in else, you don't need to add it. If that doesn't solve your problem there may be an issue with the call to `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` ?

```
<section class="slider-wrapper" <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) echo 'style="background: url("' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . '")"'; ?>>
```

Comment: it will return url with space between them